# An inequation about real pairwise commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A and B be two real $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB=BA$. It’s known that $\det(A^2+B^2)\geq 0$.
I wonder if it’s true that:
For $k$ pairwise commuting real matrices $A_1,\cdots,A_k$,we have:
  $\det(\sum_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}^2)\geq0$.

Comment: Assuming that the proof outlined in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111592) is correct, every family of commuting real matrices can be approximated by convergent families of commuting diagonalisable real matrices. It follows that you may treat the problem blockwise and the problem boils down to the scalar case and the $2\times2$ rotation matrix case. Hence the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @user1551 , I am not entirely  convinced by your second part; in my opinion, you must show some details about the simultaneous diagonalization by blocks. In the same way, if  you simult. triangularize the matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, then you have not the hand on the orderings of the eigenvalues of our matrices.

Comment: @loupblanc My comment was wrong. In hindsight, that cited answer simply doesn't (immediately) apply to the case with more than two summands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generalize the required result as follows

Let $(A_i)_{1≤i≤p}$ be $n$-by-$n$ real matrices that are simultaneously triangularizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\det(\sum_{i=1}^p {A_i}^2)≥0$.

I raised this problem on Image, the bulletin of the ILAS; cf. (statement and solution) p.37, pb. 56.2 in

https://www.ilasic.org/IMAGE/IMAGES/image58.pdf

A reader provided a solution (cf. the above reference) that uses the block decomposition proposed by user1551. I proposed another solution that I can detail if you are interested.